# Get an attribute value using SimpleXML for PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I use SimpleXMLElement class for working with xml files in my project.

My question is: how to get an attribute value of some tag with some attribute? You may assume I know the name of the tag, the name of the attribute and it's location inside the xml file. For example, for such a string `<someTag cp="c2">` knowing values 'someTag' and 'cp' I want to obtain the string "c2".

Thanks is advance.

Comment: The manual has some nice [introductory examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), which include accessing basic attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `attributes()` function on the node to get it's attributes:

```
$xml_str = '<xml>
    <node>
        <someTag cp="c2">content</someTag>
    </node>
</xml>';
$res = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);

$items = $res->xpath("//someTag");
var_dump((string) $items[0]->attributes()->cp);
```

The returned element is an `SimpleXMLElement`, so in order to use it I converted it to string (using the `(string)` cast).

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you )

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex for most use cases. The simple version is `var_dump((string) $res->someTag['cp'])`

Comment: Oops, sorry, misread the example; it would be `$res->node->someTag['cp']`. You get the idea, I hope.