# Foreach string parameter PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I parse XML like this

```
<offer internal-id="3">
<floor>2</floor>
<name>Building 1</name>
<image>picture.jpg</image>
<image tag="plan">plan.png</image>
</offer>
```

And i have function like this

```
$file = simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");


if($file === FALSE)
die("Error");
$xml = [];


foreach($file->offer as $offer)
    {
    if((string)$offer->{'location'}->{'address'} == 'Building 1')
        {
        $flat["floor"] = (string)$offer->{'floor'};
        echo $flat['png'];
        $xml[] = $flat;
        }
    }
```

And it's work fine, i can get «floor» parameter, but how I can variable offer «internal-id» and get variable image only with tag «plan»?

Comment: Please show how you are parsing the XML into an object

Comment: $file = simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");


if($file === FALSE)
die("Error");
$xml = [];


foreach($file->offer as $offer)
    {
    if((string)$offer->{'location'}->{'address'} == 'Building 1')
        {
        $flat["floor"] = (string)$offer->{'floor'};
        echo $flat['png'];
        $xml[] = $flat;
        }
    }

Comment: Please edit your original question and put that code in there

Comment: Done. And im trying to do something like this $flat["png"] = (string)$offer->{'image'}['tag="plan"'];

Comment: So basically your question is about how to get an attribute using simplexml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get an attribute value using SimpleXML for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363821/get-an-attribute-value-using-simplexml-for-php)

Comment: I'm trying this
$flat["png"] = (string)$offer->{'image'}->tag['plan'];
But it's not working

Comment: If you're looking for the contents of an `<image>` element, but only if it has an attribute of `tag="plan"`, easiest way is to use xpath: `$flat['png'] = (string) $offer->xpath('image[@tag="plan"]')[0];`

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: And if i'm trying to get image like this $flat["png"] = (string)$offer->{'image'}[1]; its also not working

Comment: Your sample xml doesn't have either `location` or `address`. and `Building 1` is the text value of `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple attribute array access to get `internal-id`:

```
$flat['internal-id'] = (string) $offer['internal-id'];
```

For the plan, you can use an xpath expression:

```
$flat['png'] = (string) $offer->xpath('image[@tag="plan"]')[0];
```

Comment: thank you so much